# Loop through array in Ruby/Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

As I'm pretty much a beginner with Rails I wanted to know how best to loop through an array and modify some values. The array is being rendered to a view where the jQuery will receive the data and display it. I want to do the hard work in the Controller (or I might switch to the model at a later date).

The array is called `@invoices` but in the array is a timestamp which I want to format.

The code to format is:

```
Time.at(@invoice.date).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Could someone show me how to loop through and overwrite the timestamp value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible syntax for a ruby loop would be.-

```
@invoices.each do |invoice|
    invoice.date = Time.at(invoice.date).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
end
```

Comment: thanks - I actually had this at one point - its the DO YOUR STUFF bit that is going wrong!

Comment: would it be `@invoices.date = Time.at(invoice.date).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: @tommyd456 not `@invoice`, just `invoice`. The block's variable is defined by `|invoice|`, nothing is setting `@invoice` for you.

Comment: that's it - I was soooo close! ha ha - I will tick as correct when it lets me

Comment: I said I would tick it on my previous comment! ha ha

Comment: Ups, sorry, missed that part :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you concerned is how to present the data. This is not the logic belongs to controller.

A better way is to do it in model. Suppose you using JSON to render data to jQuery, you just need to add a present method and override as_json

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Add a method to present the original date
  def formatted_date
    Time.at(self.date).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
  end

  # Include above method in Controller's to_json and remove old :date
  def as_json(options)
    super(method: :formatted_date, except: :date)
  end
end
```

Then in controller you need to do nothing.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that I might shift logic to model in my question so this is great - thanks

Comment: but which bit goes where? I'm not quite sure about your second comment in your sample code

Comment: I should mention that the data I'm using is from an API which is already formatted to json

Comment: Tommy, your controller will call `to_json`, so what you need to do it to manipulate the `to_json` output in model level which will need change on `as_json`. This is not controller's business.

Comment: If data is from API it's still a model. If you are not using model to represent the API result but deal with it in controller, you are wrong.

Comment: I'm all for putting logic in the model - so I'm not disagreeing

Comment: Yes that's it, don't touch `render json: ....`, override that in model, that's what I was for :)

Comment: And I use a service object to handle the API requests - I don't have a dedicated model for this

Comment: Then the service object should do his job to prepare right data for controller.

Comment: so would the `as_json` part go in the service object? - not quite sure how that would work?

Comment: When you get a chance could you help me get this approach going in a Service Object - all the tutorials online are using a model but I don't have a model

Comment: @tommyd456, it doesn't matter you call it service object or other. Who collect the data has the responsibility to modify it before passing to controller. Or another alternative is to use jQuery to process the date format directly, after all this is about how to present data.

Comment: Yes but where would the as_json method go in order for it to be called automatically? And how would the controllers call look?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't clear if you are sending just the dates to JQuery. If so, you can do this in your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html { render :json => @invoices.collect {|invoice| invoice.date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")} }
end
```

Note the absence of `@` before `invoice` within the block since `invoice` is the alias for the individual element in the array currently being processed.

If you want the whole invoice, it is only slightly more complicated, and there is a bunch of Ruby cleverness that can minimize the number of lines.

Comment: I'm sending the invoices array to jQuery where I will then iterate through the results - I just thought it would be best to sort the date into the desired format before sending.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change your data, if you only want to to display it in a specific format.

Rails allows you to change the format how a `Date` is rendered in views (specific per locale):

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      my_format: "%d/%m/%Y"

# in the view
<%= l invoice.date, format: :my_format %>
```

(see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats)

Or (if you do not need locale support) you add our own format to the `to_formatted_s` method:

```
# in config/initializers/date_formats.rb
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:my_format] = "%d/%m/%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:my_format] = "%d/%m/%Y"

# in the view
<%= invoice.date.to_s(:my_format) %>
```

(see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s)

Comment: but it's jQuery that's rendering the data

Comment: It is not clear how you send your data. Even if you send your data directly via `render :json => @invoices` It would be better to use a date format that is defined globally: Than use my second approach with `@invoices.map { |invoice| invoice.date.to_s(:my_format) }` If you give it a better name that `my_format` it is reusable everywhere in the app and you do not need to remember this pattern `"%d/%m/%Y"`. And it is easier to change to another pattern later.